# The BarcodeScanner plugin in ngCordova doesnt work in Android 6

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I'm developing in Ionic Framework.The barcodeScanner plugin(ngCordova) doesn't work for the newest version of Android.
I suspect the plugin is not updated for this version.
Any of you have found a solution? Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any error on installing ngCordova barcodescanner plugin

Comment: No, I'm not. I installed the apk in Android 5 and the plugin runs correctly...

Comment: send me your code so that i will try to understand what is going on

Comment: I'm calling to this function in the view :$scope.readCode = function() {
         
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then( 
      function(imagenEscaneada) {
        alert(imagenEscaneada.text);
      }, 
      function(error){
        alert('An error has ocurred: ' + error);
      }
    );
  };

Comment: problem resolved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samuel Paredes, There is many change in Android 6(M) , the main is runtime permissions, so we need the camera for the barcode scanner , but the plugin is not yet updated for that so we need to On the Camera permisson for the application manuully.

```
Setting >> APP manager >> Your App >> Permissions >>Camera >>
```

Please enable the camera permission from there.
Hope it will help you

Comment: Is there a way to make our application request the camera permissions?

Comment: Yes, there is a way , we need to customise our plugin for barcode scanner to access permissions

Comment: @A-DroidTech how can I do to ask permissions on app installation?? My app isn't working because user has no access to the camera...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have this problem too. To solve it we have done this : ionic platform add android@4.1 and it solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem: Sorry, the android camera encountered a problem. You may need to restar the device

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nHW3.png

Answer (score 0):

Droid Tech, will this be resolved in the near future? Is there some way to monitor or to get a notification when this bug is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Same error happened to me. A guy on Github forked the plug-in and fixed it, take a look [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/167#issuecomment-212794938).

basically, remove the barcode scanner plugin you have right now and add the new one like this:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/jrontend/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`

It works exactly the same way.